# Modifying a matrix element in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, window, command, element

I have a Matrix of 3 columns and N rows. I'm trying to modify an element and see that element (by not putting the semi-colon). For a reason, it always gives me the whole row.

Here's the code and what it does :

```
for i=1:N
   [fitG params resnorm residual]=lorentzfit3(X,Y,[]);
   PICSG(i,1)= params(2)
   PICSG(i,2)= params(5)
   PICSG(i,3)= params(8) 
end
```

X and Y are given for every N. Params has 10 parameters in exit. Here is the command window result when I run this code.

```
PICSG =
2.6288e+09

PICSG =
1.0e+09 *
2.6288    2.8425

PICSG =
1.0e+09 *
2.6288    2.8425    2.7368
```

Why is it showing all the PICSG instead of only the one I asked for?

Answer (score 1):

When you do PICSG(i,1) = params(2), you are not asking Matlab to show PICSG(i,1), you are doing an assigment and by not adding a semi-colon you are asking MATLAB to show the result of that assigment.

After an assignment, if no semi-colon is used, MATLAB shows all the modified matrix and not only the changed valued.

If you want to display the value use:

```
for i=1:N
   [fitG params resnorm residual]=lorentzfit3(X,Y,[]);
   PICSG(i,1)= params(2); disp(PICSG(i,1));
   PICSG(i,2)= params(5); disp(PICSG(i,2));
   PICSG(i,3)= params(8); disp(PICSG(i,3));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

preallocate memory for PICSG

```
PICSG = zeros(N, 3)
```

Comment: after assignment MATLAB show all matrix. For one elemen use disp(PICSG(i,3)) or PICSG(i, 3) on a separate line.